# React, Graphql CRUD app - delete mutation deletes first in list

Tags: reactjs, graphql

I'm trying to create a simple CRUD demo in React using Graphql.

I have the backend working and I have the create and read.

I'm outputing a list of Recipe names and have an input field to add to the list.

Each Recipe in the list has a delete button to delete that recipe.

I have the delete working but instead of deleteing the Recipe clicked it always the deletes the first Recipe in the list.

The correct id is being passed to the delete Mutation but the network tabs shows the id of the first recipe in the list.

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong.

**Server-side**

schema.js

```
exports.typeDefs = `

  type Recipe{
    _id: ID
    name: String
    description: String
  }

  type Query{
    recipe:[Recipe]
  }

  type Mutation{
    addRecipe(name: String!, description: String):Recipe,
    deleteRecipe(_id: ID):Recipe
  }

`
```

resolvers.js

```
exports.resolvers = {

  Query: {
    recipe: async (obj, args, { Recipe }, info) => {
      const allRecipes = await Recipe.find()
      return allRecipes
    }
  },
  Mutation: {
    addRecipe: async (obj, { name, description }, { Recipe }, info) => {
      const newRecipe = await new Recipe({
        name,
        description
      }).save()
      return newRecipe
    },
    deleteRecipe: async (obj, { id }, { Recipe }, info) => {
      const recipe = await Recipe.findOneAndRemove({ id })
      return recipe
    }
  }
}
```

**client**

queries/index.tsx

```
import { gql } from 'apollo-boost';

export const GET_ALL_RECIPES = gql`
  query RecipeData{
    recipe{
      _id
      name
      description
    }
  }
`
export const ADD_RECIPE = gql`
  mutation addRecipe($name: String!, $description:String){
    addRecipe(name: $name, description: $description){
      _id
      name
      description
    }
  }
`
export const DELETE_RECIPE = gql`
  mutation deleteRecipe($id: ID!){
    deleteRecipe(_id: $id){
      _id
      name
      description
    }
  }
`
```

App.tsx

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import './App.css';

import { RecipeData } from '../generated/RecipeData';
import { GET_ALL_RECIPES, ADD_RECIPE, DELETE_RECIPE } from '../queries';
import { useQuery, useMutation } from 'react-apollo-hooks';


const App: React.FC = () => {

  const [name, setName] = useState<string>('')
  const [description, setDes] = useState<string>('')
  const [recipeId, setRecipeId] = useState<string>('')

  useEffect(() => {
    deleteRecipe()
    console.log('recipeId = ', recipeId)
  }, [recipeId])

  const handleNameChange = (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    setName(e.target.value)
  }

  const handleDesChange = (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    setDes(e.target.value)
  }

  const handleClick = (e: React.MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement>) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    createRecipe()
  };

  const handelDelete = (e: React.MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement>) => {
    setRecipeId(e.target.parentElement.getAttribute("data-id"))
  }

  const [deleteRecipe] = useMutation(DELETE_RECIPE, {
    variables: { id: recipeId }, refetchQueries: ['RecipeData']
  })

  const [createRecipe, { error }] = useMutation(ADD_RECIPE, {
    variables: { name, description }, refetchQueries: ['RecipeData']
  })
  if (error) {
    console.error('erroring : ', error)
  }

  const { data, loading } = useQuery<RecipeData | null>(GET_ALL_RECIPES, {
    suspend: false
  })

  if (loading || !data) return <div>Loading</div>

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Graphql</h1>
      <ul>
        {
          data.recipe !== null && data.recipe.map((recipe, i) => (
            <li key={recipe._id} data-id={recipe._id}>
              {recipe.name}
              <button onClick={handelDelete}>X</button>
            </li>
          ))
        }
      </ul>

      <form>
        <div>
          <label>Name</label>
          <input
            type="text"
            value={name}
            onChange={handleNameChange}
          />
        </div>
        <div>
          <label>Description</label>
          <input
            type="text"
            value={description}
            onChange={handleDesChange}
          />
        </div>
        <button onClick={handleClick}>Add Recipe</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: resolver doesn't use `_id`

Comment: There is no reason to use `useEffect` here at all. It unnecessarily complicates your code. Just call `deleteRecipe` directly from `handleDelete`, passing the `data-id` in as a variable. You can pass variables to either the hook or the mutate function.

Comment: I don't have `_id` in the resolver

Comment: How can I pass variables to the mutate function